# make a CASE with another case In SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one question I make a view with lot of case for a flag view .

I need to make a CASE with another CASE, but I don't know what is the easiest way, I don't know if I have to quote the CASE every time because if it is the case my SQL may be very long. Another solution  ?

```
SELECT

SR.SERVICE_REQUEST_ID,
SR.COMPLAINT_DATE_YYYYMMDD,



-- Contact Center RSF 

CASE
    WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION IN  ('CX - CC BACK OFFICE 1', 'CX - CC MIDDLE OFFICE')
         THEN 'BUSINESS(BO)'

    WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION LIKE '%Dispatcher%'
         THEN 'BUSINESS'
         
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION = 'CX - CC INFODESK'
         THEN 'BUSINESS(FO)'         
         
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION LIKE '%FINES%' OR CUR_DD.DIVISION   LIKE '%INAMI%'
         THEN 'FINES'    
           
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION LIKE '%Key Account%'
         THEN 'KASD'         
         
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION LIKE '%Philately %'
         THEN 'PHILATELY' 
         
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION LIKE '%PI%'
   OR CUR_DD.DIVISION LIKE '%Postinfo %'
         THEN 'POSTINFO'       
         
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION = 'CX - CC BACK OFFICE 2'
         THEN 'PRESS' 
          
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION = 'CC FO First Line' OR  CUR_DD.DIVISION  LIKE '%MRS_CC%' OR  CUR_DD.DIVISION  LIKE '%DMM%'   OR  CUR_DD.DIVISION  LIKE '%Parcels%'  OR  CUR_DD.DIVISION  LIKE '%International%'
         THEN 'RESISENTIAL' 
         
   WHEN CUR_DD.DIVISION LIKE '%RSS VIP%'
         THEN 'VIP'      
         
               
         END AS "Contact center RSF",

--SLA Back Office 

CASE 

"CONTACT CENTER RSF" = 'FINES'

THEN YES

END AS "TEST3",
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks, I try but I have one error message with select . Check screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest `CASEs`, with just parentheses; for example:

```
with testTable (x) as (
    select 'one' from dual UNION ALL
    select 'two' from dual
)
select x,
       case (
               case
                when x = 'one' then 1
                when x = 'two' then 2
               end
            )
        when 1 then 'value one'
        when 2 then 'value two'
       end
from testTable
```

Of course, another way could be by rewriting your code to use just one `CASE` to handle all the logics, for example this is the same then the previous one:

```
with testTable (x) as (
    select 'one' from dual UNION ALL
    select 'two' from dual
)
select x,
       case
        when x = 'one' then 'value one'
        when x = 'two' then 'value two'
       end
from testTable
```

Just for completeness, consider that you can use more complicated conditions in `CASE`, for example:

```
CASE
    when a = 'kk' and (b=1 or not c = 8) ...
    ...
```

Comment: The parentheses around the nested CASE are unnecessary: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0668df10e3370a9fd882992aa8d59691

Comment: I'm new worker in SQL and WITH syntax is complicated .. .